# Storing component into a variable and reuse it

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Ok i got components imported as

```
import Payment from './pages/payment';
import Chat from './pages/chat';
```

Now I am using `Drawer` component and using it together with `Navigator` my renderScene become something like this

```
if( route.id == 'payment'){
    return  <Drawer  xx={} yy={} and a lot more >
              <Payment navigator={navigator} />
            </Drawer>
}

if(route.id == 'chat'){
    return <Drawer  xx={} yy={} and a lot more >
              <Chat navigator={navigator} />
            </Drawer>
}
```

Those lengthy `Drawer` code are being used again and again.  I want to store that `<Payment navigator={navigator} >` or the other into a variable and then return that with `Drawer` only once.

How can i store it and return it with Drawer?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if you are asking this but what about something like:

```
const routes = {
 payment: Payment,
 chat: Chat
 ...
}
```

And then, just:

```
const Scene = routes[route.id];
return (
  <Drawer>
    <Scene navigator={navigator}/>
  </Drawer>
)
```

Comment: Thanks you. I actually tried very similar to this before but was using `var` instead of `const` and it was giving me error. Changed to `const` and it work :)

Answer (score 2):

Here you have 3 options:

```
// 1. Group the drawer props in an object
const drawerProps = {
  xx: ...,
  yy: ...
};
<Drawer {...drawerProps}>
  <Chat navigator={navigator} />    
</Drawer>

// 2. Define a wrapper object that populates the common Drawer props
const CustomDrawer = ({ children }) => (
  <Drawer  xx={} yy={} and a lot more>
    {children}
  </Drawer>
);


// 3. Define a wrapper object that populates the common Drawer props with default props. (Can be 
// overriden.)
const CustomDrawer = ({ 
  xx='XX',
  yy='YY',
  children 
}) => (
  <Drawer  xx={xx} yy={yy} and a lot more>
    {children}
  </Drawer>
);
```

**EDIT:** I missunderstood your question, for storing the inner part you just have to assign it to a varible and use it.

```
const routes = {
  chat: <Chat navigator={navigator} />,
  payment: <Payment navigator={navigator} />,  
}


<Drawer {...drawerProps}>
  { routes[route.id] }
</Drawer>
```

Comment: Thanks , very similar approach to accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I propose this solution with a **React hook** (React v16.8+).

The `useMemo` returns a component according to the `route` agument passed to the `switch`. The `useMemo` is updated each time one of the internal variables (passed as a second argument as `route`) is updated.

```js
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';

export default function App ({
    route,
    navigator
}) {
    const [route, setRoute] = useState('payment');

    const mainContent = useMemo(() => {
        return () => {
            switch (route) {
                case 'payment':
                    return (
                        <Payment navigator={navigator} />
                    );
    
                case 'chat':
                    return (
                        <Chat navigator={navigator} />
                    );
            }
        }
    }, [route, navigator])
    
    return (
        <Drawer xx={} yy={} and a lot more >
            { mainContent() }
        </Drawer>
    );
}
```